# How to customize the Jenkins Autogenrated mail for Robot Framework tests?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I am running all my Robot Framework tests through Jenkins. Jenkins sending Auto generated Result mail, with the content of, Jenkins Job run console output.

My requirement is, the autogenerated mail's BODY should contain console output of Pybot run (shown below)

**MAIL SUBJECT Line should contain :**

```
Total Tests = 4, PASS = 0, FAIL = 4
```

**MAIL BODY Should contain the below output:**

```
C:\Users\test\Desktop\FINAL WORKING COPY OF SCRIPTS>pybot sample_test_testsui
te.robot
==============================================================================
Sample test testsuite
==============================================================================
TESTCASE1 : TEST-01 - HJ amouallation in jkfault locati               .Second si
gnal will force exit.
TESTCASE1 : TEST-01 - HJ amouallation in jkfault locati               | FAIL |
Execution terminated by signal
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TESTCASE2 : TEST-01 - Teske1n: Kendows: Verify that teskencesste s... | FAIL |
Test execution stopped due to a fatal error.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TESTCASE3 : TEST-01 - Teske1n Control (Start HJ): jkldows             | FAIL |
Test execution stopped due to a fatal error.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TESTCASE4 : TEST-01, TEST-01 - Teske2n Control (Stop HJ): opndows     | FAIL |
Test execution stopped due to a fatal error.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Direct install testsuite                                              | FAIL |
4 critical tests, 0 passed, 4 failed
4 tests total, 0 passed, 4 failed
==============================================================================
Output:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\FINAL WORKING COPY OF SCRIPTS\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\test\Desktop\FINAL WORKING COPY OF SCRIPTS\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\test\Desktop\FINAL WORKING COPY OF SCRIPTS\report.html
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

C:\Users\test\Desktop\FINAL WORKING COPY OF SCRIPTS>
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Robot Framework or Jenkins?

Please guide me with your ideas.

Comment: @Brayan Oakley Do you have any idea on this issue? Please throw any idea to achieve this. Thanks.